# Express + Passport : How to use req.user variable in MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, express, passport.js

I hope someone can help with.  Apologies if its simple, I've been searching the web for hours and havn't round the right answer.

I'm using Express with Passport.  I have logins working and req.user is being populated with the user_id from the database which comes out in this format when console.log'ing it:

```
req.session.passport.user: {"user":{"user_id":18} }
```

So that's good.  Now I'm moving onto another page and trying to use that variable in a new MYSQL query to get more information from the user out of my database like so:

```
user = req.user;
db.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 'user'", function(error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log(results)
      });
```

I can't get this to work after trying to strip the user_id variable down to just numbers, etc.  Can anyone suggest a method to get the req.user variable into a usable format fitting a MYSQL query (being just the number so I can match it against the proper field)?  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for reading!

Regards,
Daniel

Comment: What about : "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id =  ${user}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) just as follow,

```
db.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ${req.user.user_id}`, function(error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log(results)
});
```

Or

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE id =" + req.user.user_id
```

Comment: DININDU, Winner winner, chicken dinner.  Thank you sir your edit of ""SELECT * FROM users WHERE id =" + req.user.user_id" did the trick.  Thank you so much, that's been driving me freaking crazy, now I can move forward, have a great day!